# SQL Server Management Studio 2018 Will Not Start

Tags: sql-server

I have SSMS 2018 installed on Win10 and it keeps on refusing to start. I click the icon, I hear a windows audible error but no error message shows. I had the same issue before so I uninstalled and reinstalled SSMS. The problem is resolved for maybe a day (or possibly a few restarts) but then reappears. I had enterprise and developer edition of SQL server installed so uninstalled enterprise as do not need it.

I stumbled across one nugget of information. If I do a net start mssqlserver from the cmd prompt I see "system error 5 has occurred Access is denied."

All the MSSQL services seem to log on as Local System - I had read that the wrong user here could cause the issue

Comment: I'd suggest you check your Event Viewer logs to see if there's a message given on unsuccessful startup.Some of your MSSQL services should run under `NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT` and others `NT Service\MSSQLSERVER`

Comment: I have the same problem. It run well yesterday (I even created a DB and some tables). Now after trying an application that is supposed to link to the DB, studio won't start